# Error in Linear algebra 4E - Friedberg, Insel, Spence?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Does the lack of "for all" in (g) make this statement false?

Exercise 1, part (g):

If $x, y$, and $z$ are vectors in an inner product space such that $\langle x, y\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle$, then $y=z$.

But on page 333:

Theorem 6.1. Let $\mathrm{V}$ be an inner product space. Then for $x, y, z \in \mathrm{V}$ and $c \in F$, the following statements are true.

(a) $\langle x, y+z\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle+\langle x, z\rangle$.

(b) $\langle x, c y\rangle=\bar{c}\langle x, y\rangle$.

(c) $\langle x, 0\rangle=\langle 0, x\rangle=0$.

(d) $\langle x, x\rangle=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

(e) If $\langle x, y\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle$ for all $x \in \mathrm{V}$, then $y=z$.

**I have so far:**

Proof:
$\langle x, y\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle \Leftrightarrow\langle x, y-z\rangle=0, \forall x \in V$ so you can take $x=y-z$ and get $\|y-z\|^2=0 \Rightarrow y=z$

Counter example:

Let $x=(1,0), y=(0,1)$, and $z=(0,-1)$. Then we have $\langle x, y\rangle=$ $\langle x, z\rangle=0$, but $y \neq z$

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a "for all $x\in V$" in the hypothesis of (e).

Comment: The point of the exercise was for you to understand the necessity of the "for all" in the hypothesis of (e). Without it, the statement, as you showed, is indeed false.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reviewing the questions, I see my mistake, thanks to Sassatelli and Ted for confirming that the for all was indeed the issue:

The theorem says

IF the equality is true **FOR ALL** $x$, THEN $z=y$

While the (g) says

IF the equality is true **FOR ONE** $x$, THEN $z=y$